# C Struct inside union inside struct

Tags: c, struct, unions

How do i initialize a variable of structure B or C?

```
typedef struct _A
{
  union
  {
    struct
    {
      int b;
    } B;
    struct
    {
      int c;
    } C;
  } u;
} A;
```

Something like 
`A.u.B *bVar;` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your structure aside.

```
typedef struct {
    int b;
} B;
```

Comment: you mean declare B and C separately and include them inside the union in A as `typedef struct _A  { union { struct B b; struct C c;} u; } A;`

Comment: Yeah. Then you can use this type.

Comment: @Nitrate but beware that if you declare a standalone `B` it will not automatically be part of an enclosing `A`.

Comment: @Alnitak yes i understand that

Comment: @Nitrate if you've already `typedef B` and `C` then your `A` is just `typedef struct { union { B b; C c; } u; } A;` - there's no need to use `struct` to refer to `B` and `C` any more.

Answer (score 5):

The `typedef` only covers `A`, not the union or structures defined therein.

`typedef` can't be nested like that - each user-defined "type" must have a single label, so a declaration of a variable of type `A.u.B` is illegal.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
/* Initialise to zero */
A a = {{{0},{0}}};
/* Now set the b to 5 */
a.u.B.b = 5;
```

If you watch the curly brackets carefully, you will see that they exactly match the brackets in the type declaration. So the first brace begins `A`, the second begins `A.u`, the third begins `A.u.B`, and the first `0` corresponds to `A.u.B.b`. The close brace finishes `A.u.B`, then the comma means the next opening brace begins `A.u.C`, so the second zero initialises `A.u.C.c`, then all the braces close again.

Note anonymous structs may not be supported by all compilers. I cannot remember whether they are allowed by the standard or not...

Comment: So i can't initialize as `A.u.B b = 5` ??

Comment: @Nitrate no, because (per my answer) there's no such type as `A.u.B`.  You have to declare a variable of type `A` and then set its contents.

Comment: @Alnitak is correct, it is not really 'A.u.B' I have just used that notation to explain how the braces work to initialise.